# Duda con GET enviando datos

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una lista de usuarios:

```
<link>user1<link>
<link>user2<link>
<link>user3<link>
.
.
etc.
```

Cuando hago clic en esos enlaces, la *URL* cambia, por ejemplo: `miAplicacion/user1`, `miAplicacion/user2`... etcétera.

En mi servidor tengo ya los *GET* **estáticos** para los usuarios:

```
app.get('/user1', function(req, res, next) {
app.get('/user2', function(req, res, next) {
app.get('/user3', function(req, res, next) {
```

¿Cómo hacerlo dinámico, en vez de estático?

*aunque no necesito precisamente en nodejs, porque creo que esta forma es igual en varios lenguajes.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta esto:

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
   var idUser = req.params.id;
});
```

En vez de tener varias funciones `app.get()`, mejor remplazalas por solo una. a la funciona de arriba solo debes pasarle el id del usuario que tu quieres, entonces los enlaces deberían ser así: `/user/1` o `/user/238`. En cualquier caso la variable `idUser'  debería recuperar el id que le pases por URL.

Comment: me explicas detalladamente porfavor,

Comment: A ver, En vez de tener varias funciones app.get(), mejor reemplazalas por solo una. a la funciona de arriba solo debes pasarle el id del usuario que tu quieres, entonces los links deberían ser asi: /user/1 o /user/238. En cualquier caso la variable **idUser** debería recuperar el id que le pases por **URL**.

Comment: lo probare y te comento

Comment: No es magia. Lo que hace express es simplemente mapear el listener a `/user`, pero cuando determina qué ruta usar, en interno, primero verifica si la petición entrante tiene parámetros, así puede diferenciar `/user` de `/user/algo`. El sufijo `id` es usado internamente para asociarlo con el parámetro recibido y ponerlo en el objeto `Request` de Express, así puedes obtenerlo vía `request.params.id`.

Comment: @guzgarcia algun link porfavor quiero saber sobre esto

Comment: Consulta [la documentación oficial](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Answer (score 1):

Bastaría con definir un solo endpoint en el servidor que reciba parámetros dinámicos. El endpoint debería ser algo en específico, por ejemplo un endpoint para usuarios, como en tu caso, para node js express sería algo como:

```
app.get('/user/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  db.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    if(err) return res.status(500).end('Error ocurred on querying db');
    // Renderizar algun template de usuarios:
    return res.status(200).render('user_template', user.toJSON());
  });
});
```

De esta manera, cualquier ruta solicitada que cumpla con el patron `/user/something` por método `GET` será manejada por el endpoint de arriba. Para más información, consulta la [documentación de express](http://expressjs.com/es/guide/routing.html).

En cuanto al lado del cliente solo tienes que definir una forma para hacer que tus usuarios entren en dicho endpoint, ya sea mediante links:

```
<a href="/user/1">User 1</a>
```

o mediante ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/user/' + id,
  type: 'GET',
  .
  .
  .
});
```